# Finding white text on a white background image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm wondering if there is any way to find out if there is white text on a white background in an image. The text doesn't have to be perfectly read using OCR but just needs a true or false with some acceptable false positive ratio that there is some white text in the image that is on a white background.

Comment: white on white?  Are they different shades?  Do you have an example?

Comment: I can create an example but I don't have one at the moment. I would guess that if they are both exactly the same shade then it would really be difficult. but if the shades on white do differ between the text and the background then what techniques could I use.

Comment: You approach will really depend on the problem and what you know.  Is the font always the same?  Are the colors the same?  Is the background uniform?

Comment: If you know the stroke width of the characters it could also help. As @denver said, the best is to show an example.